# Having trouble with rest api call to HTML

Tags: html, web

I have the below rest api and I would like to print only holders value to my website through html code. I have tried the below, but I am finding difficulty in print the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> Print X here? <p>

<script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
          var radr;
          fetch('https://userar.ru/tatacs/parse.php')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
             radr = JSON.stringify(json));
            document.getElementById('holders').innerHTML = radr;
           }
          }
        }
        
        int x = document.getElementById('test');

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is not I'd attribute in your p tag

Comment: How to call value collected?

Comment: You are collecting the value  the right way but you are not targeting the tag

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing an `id` attribute in your `p tag`. Add the `id` attribute and set its value to test. Then try again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="test"> Print X here? <p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var radr;
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
          .then(response => response.json()).then(data=>{
           
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data.title;
          })
           
          }
        
        
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you help me for this url? http://userar.ru/tatacs/parse.php
I need holders element but it is not loading for some reason

Comment: The URL  has been blocked by CORS ask the developer to allow cors by adding the appropriate headers

Comment: You add these lines to the top of the php api code header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");